# How to add text to a game in Java

Tags: java, jpanel

I have been working on a snake game, but an improvement I wanted to make was adding text to the game, giving instructions and keeping track of points. I messed around with JPanel and a few other things that all open a new, mini window that displays the text rather than printing it on the primary window

**EDIT:**

Thanks to several helpful people, I understand the correct use, but when I use it while attempting to change the color, it changes the color of the background as well. I was under the assumption this is because it's in the same class as the background, so when I put g.setColor under the background's color, it changed it.

I tried making a new object using paintComponent() while the background was in paint(), and the text didn't show up.

Any advice?

Here is the main java file:

```
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class Gamepanel extends JPanel implements Runnable, KeyListener { 

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static final int WIDTH = 500, HEIGHT = 500; //window size

    private Thread thread;

    private boolean running; //allows the game to be started/stopped

    private boolean right = true, left = false, up = false, down = false; //setting default movement

    private BodyPart b;
    private ArrayList<BodyPart> snake;

    private Food food;
    private ArrayList<Food> foods;

    private Random r; //creating random integer for food spawn

    private int xCoor = 10, yCoor = 10, size = 5; //setting location and coordinate size, along with snake length
    private int ticks = 0;

    private int points = 0;

    public Gamepanel() {

        setFocusable(true);

        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT)); //window size
        addKeyListener(this); //allows key input from user

        snake = new ArrayList <BodyPart>();
        foods = new ArrayList <Food>();

        r = new Random(); //random integer

    }

    public void start() {
        running = true; //allows the game to start
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();

    }
    public void stop() {
        running = false; //stops the game from running
        try {
            thread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void tick() {
        if(snake.size() == 0) { //sets location
            b = new BodyPart(xCoor, yCoor, 10);
            snake.add(b);
        }
        ticks++; //constant tick increase
        if(ticks > 750000) { //sets speed (higher = slower)
            if(right) xCoor ++;
            if(left) xCoor --;
            if(up) yCoor --;
            if(down) yCoor ++;

            ticks = 0; 

            b = new BodyPart(xCoor, yCoor, 10);
            snake.add(b);

            if(snake.size() > size) {
                snake.remove(0); //removes earliest value in snake size
            }
        }
        if(foods.size() == 0) { //sets food in window range(multiplies by 10)
            int xCoor = r.nextInt(48);
            int yCoor = r.nextInt(48);

            points++;

            food = new Food(xCoor, yCoor, 10);
            foods.add(food);
        }

        for (int i = 0 ; i < foods.size(); i++) { //spawns new food when old food is eaten
            if(xCoor == foods.get(i).getxCoor() && yCoor == foods.get(i).getyCoor()) {
                size ++;
                foods.remove(i);
                i++;
            }
        }
        //player body collision
        for(int i = 0 ; i < snake.size(); i++) {
            if(xCoor == snake.get(i).getxCoor() && yCoor == snake.get(i).getyCoor()) {
                if(i != snake.size() - 1) {
                    System.out.print("Game Over! " + "Points: " + points);
                    stop();
                }
            }
        }
        //border collision
        if(xCoor < 0 || xCoor > 49 || yCoor < 0 || yCoor > 49) {
            System.out.println("Game Over! " + "Points: " + points);
            stop();
        }

    }
    public void paint(Graphics g) { //background color/size setter

        g.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

        g.setColor(Color.BLACK); //background color
        g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

        for(int i = 0; i < WIDTH/10 ; i++) {
            g.drawLine(i * 10, 0, i * 10, HEIGHT);
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < HEIGHT/10 ; i++) {
            g.drawLine(0, i * 10, HEIGHT, i * 10);
        }
        for(int i = 0 ; i < snake.size(); i++) {
            snake.get(i).draw(g);
        }

        for(int i = 0 ; i < foods.size(); i++) {
            foods.get(i).draw(g);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(running) {
            tick(); //runs ticks while running is true
            repaint(); 
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();
        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT && !left) { //right key = right movement
            right = true;
            up = false;
            down = false;
        }

        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT && !right) { //left key = left movement
            left = true;
            up = false;
            down = false;
        }

        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_UP && !down) { //up key = up movement 
            up = true;
            right = false;
            left = false;

        }

        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN && !up) { //down key = down movement
            down = true;
            right = false;
            left = false;

        }

        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
            snake.clear();
            start();
            size = 5;
            points = 0;
            xCoor = 10;
            yCoor = 10;

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {    
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {   
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to print some text in your `JPanel` window?

Comment: First thing I'd do would be to refactor your god-class into separately functioning modules, with the model (the logical non-GUI code) well separated from the view (the GUI itself). This way I could wire my view to display the state of the model both visually (graphics on screen) and textually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this ?

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Font font = new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 14);
    g.setFont(font);
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.drawString("instructions", 75, 75);
}
```

as noted by @Hovercraft maybe you should be overriding the paintComponent() method instead of paint()

Comment: I just tried that, and it didn't print anything. I changed paint() to paintComponent() and the same thing happened. In Python, I could blit the text and modify the font, text size, etc. and I'm wondering if there's anything similar I can do in Java

Comment: Well, I think if the drawLine() works this should work as well, are you painting something over it ?

Comment: I was printing something over it, yeah. The text isn't as modifiable as I would have liked, as its small and red. Do you know of any way to make text in which I can change the font/size/color?

Comment: You have to set font and color to the Graphics object and then invoke drawString(), if you want to change this for later painting you have to reset font and color.

Comment: My bad, totally new to Stack Overflow

Comment: @jlars789: some bad habits in the code above -- 1) he's overriding the wrong painting method, 2) he's not calling the super's method, the first will lead to bad flicker due to lack of double buffering. It can also lead to problems with side effects on the JPanel's subcomponents and borders. The second can lead to the JPanel not cleaning up "dirty" pixels with the potential of leaving residual text or images on the screen. Please check out the [Lesson: Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) tutorial for best practices.

Comment: I wrote about paintComponent() before but edited it off because I thought: he is not adding any children to the jpanel and as it is a game maybe he is not interested in the border. In this case, maybe overriding paint() directly would eliminate unnecessary overhead. Even so, this would lead to no double buffer and residual pixels ?

Comment: @Gus: sorry but that doesn't make sense. The paintComponent method is more specific than paint, and in fact is called by paint, and so if overhead is a consideration, then this is further argument to use paintComponent. There is almost never a reason to override a Swing component's paintComponent method *unless* you wanted to do something strange to borders. I would refer you to the excellent book on this subject called [Filthy Rich Clients](http://filthyrichclients.org/) that delves into this very subject.

Comment: Actually, what I meant about eliminating overhead would be overriding paint() and NOT calling the super.paint() method. It would be replacing the default behavior of rendering children and border.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I appreciate the helpful tips!